# Sending logs as MQTT topic

Tags: logging, mqtt, mosquitto

I've been searching a few hours but couldn't find useful information. Just wondering if anyone know how to send log information by `mosquitto_pub` whenever logs get updated

I use `syslog-ng` I'd like to use `mosquitto_pub` to publish topic and message whenever the log (`/var/log/syslog` or other logs that are located in `/var/log/`) get updated.
eg.

`/var/log/syslog` new log `Started on ttyS1.`

then

`mosquitto_pub -h 127.0.0.1 -t Started on ttyS1 -m "Started on ttyS1."` automatically fires

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mosquitto_pub` supports reading messages from stdin a line at a time so something like the following will work:

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog | mosquitto_pub -t syslog -l
```

This will publish each line from `/var/log/syslog` to the topic `syslog`